# How can I write a string to a binary file?

Tags: go

such as, I write 'A' but in file it is '1000001' ,

how can I do ?

I have tried

```
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)

    data := []int8{65, 80}

    for _, i := range data {
        binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, i)

        fp.Write(buf.Bytes())
    }
```

but I got string 'AP' in file not a binary code

Comment: There is no function in the standard lib of the form `func Bits(s string) string` which would turn a string `s` into an other string containing the bits as "0" and "1". But that one should be very simple to do if you limit yourself to 7bit ASCII strings: Just output "0" or "1" depending on the rune in question beeing even or odd, then bitshift to the right and repeat 8 times. Note that absolutely no "binary" stuff is involved here as your file is **not** "binary" (whatever that means, there are no non-binary files).

Comment: The effect I want just like mongodb's store file, can I do this use golang?

Comment: So you are asking "How to convert some string to BSON with Go?"

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really understand the question, but perhaps you want something like:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.OpenFile("out.txt", os.O_TRUNC|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0600)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for _, v := range "AP" {
        fmt.Fprintf(f, "%b\n", v)
    }
    f.Close()
}
```

which gives:

```
$ cat out.txt
1000001
1010000
```

Comment: out.txt is a binary file are there are no no-binary files. Topskips answer is a very nice one and does exactly what you asked for. Maybe there is some confusion about "binary" files. Every file is binary, there are no non-binary files. If any file contains only bytes in the range 0x20 to 0x7e (around that at least) than you may call this file an "ASCII text file" (or that like) and notepad will open and display it happily, but it still is binary.